# Devops: Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows'

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, windows-10-sdk

I am trying to set up a build pipeline for the Windows Universal Sample Application [File Access Project](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess).

The pipeline is using the Azure Pipelines Hosted VS2017 Image

The solution builds when I run it in VS locally.

Package.appxmanifest contains

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10586.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.17763.0" />
```

When the pipeline tries to build the following error appears in the build task log.

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationModel' 
does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The YAML is

```
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: 
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'


- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
```

The project looks like this on my machine

[image: project references]

Where
[image: one reference]

[image: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup]

And it runs correctly.

I notice the log for the Nuget Restore task has no errors and does report

```
2018-12-16T01:27:31.8700773Z Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.0.0 with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
2018-12-16T01:27:31.8700831Z Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.0 with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
2018-12-16T01:27:31.8700878Z All packages and projects are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
```

[Update]

Looking at the location on my machine of  the SDK

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract\1.0.0.0
```

I wonder how Nuget is meant to know about that.
Indeed I wonder why it has something about MachineLearning in the path.

[Update]

I changed versions to 17134 (RS4/1803) instead of 17763 (RS5/1809) as suggested by Stefan Wick MSFT

The errors changed to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft
.AppXPackage.Targets(3218,5): Error APPX0101: A signing key is required in 
order to package this project. Please specify a PackageCertificateKeyFile or 
PackageCertificateThumbprint value in the project file.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
SharedContent\Templates\UWPSDKSampleCPP\ARM\Debug\UWPSDKSampleCPP\AppxManifest.xml(0,0):

Error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation 
error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 10, Column 13, 
Reason: 'Microsoft.SDKSamples.$safeprojectname$.CPP' violates pattern 
constraint of '[-.A-Za-z0-9]+'. The attribute 'Name' with value 
'Microsoft.SDKSamples.$safeprojectname$.CPP' failed to parse.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
SharedContent\Templates\UWPSDKSampleCS\bin\ARM\Debug\AppxManifest.xml(0,0): 
Error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: 
The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 10, Column 13, Reason: 'Microsoft.SDKSamples.$safeprojectname$.CS' violates pattern constraint of '[-.A-Za-z0-9]+'. 
The attribute 'Name' with value 'Microsoft.SDKSamples.$safeprojectname$.CS' failed to parse.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'
```

Comment: What is the output of the NuGet restore step?

Comment: @DanielMann The log for the Nuget task is too big to paste but it has no errors.

Comment: Does it work if you target 17134 (RS4/1803) instead of 17763 (RS5/1809)? The agent might not have the 1809 SDK installed yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807130/devops-error-cs0103-the-name-windows-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context  was a similar but not the same issue.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Care to write up the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that your app is targeting the 1809 SDK (v17763), which has not been rolled out on the build agents yet, due to some [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/606).

Until it has been rolled out on the agents, you have two options to get unblocked:

1. Target the 1803 SDK (v17134) if you don't actually need any APIs from the 1809 SDK - or
2. Use [this script](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/build/Install-WindowsSdkISO.ps1) to explicitely install the 17763 SDK dependency

I will update the answer once there is an update regarding the SDK rollout to build agents.