# Devops: Error CS0103: The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context

Tags: azure-devops, desktop-bridge

Similar to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798530/devops-error-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-applicationmodel-does-not-exi) I am able to build on my machine but the devops build is failing.

The Desktop Bridge Package project targets

```
Windows 10 , Version 1803, Build 17134
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Windows reference in my project it uses

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0\Windows.winmd
```

I corrected it to use

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Windows.winmd
```

The particular build error in Devops disappeared