# TFS build fails for UWP application

Tags: tfs, uwp, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have a UWP application on GitHub. I am setting up CI build for this. I followed this walkthrough.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/universal?view=vsts&tabs=github

But when build is triggered, it fails. And I get following errors,

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Navigation' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'System' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Input' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Navigation' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

NuGet packages are restored (confirmed via log), but still I am getting these errors.

Comment: Is your target version set to 17763? (Windows 10 1809 update)?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT yes,

Comment: See this answer for a workaround. Still waiting to hear from the team about a date for the fix …
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798530/devops-error-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-applicationmodel-does-not-exi/

Comment: I will try this and will let you know,

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT So I am using Microsoft.UI.Xaml in my application and it runs only on 1809 update. Would you recommend "Use this script to explicitely install the 17763 SDK dependency"?

Comment: Yes, this should unblock you for now until the update gets deployed by VSTS.